# Fitting images into Bootstrap SVGs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-5

So I'm building a webpage with Bootstrap 5 and one of the elements I'm using (from BS5 templates) is this

```
    <div class="col" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
      <div class="card shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Learn More</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, there's an `svg` tag up there with a `rect` inside. I want to display an image in place of the `rect` (or inside it, just need it to be same dimension as the `rect`) while keeping the text that's currently showing over said `rect`.

Now I know that in order to display images inside an `svg` you need to define a `clip path` using the shape you want but this looks like it was written for a better implementation.

Can anyone point out how I can put an image in the `rect` or in its place without any changes to the dimensions and still keep the text that shows over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the `<image>` tag, by setting `width` and/or `height` as `100%` - image would fill the whole container area.

```html
 <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
      <title>Placeholder</title>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" />
      <image href="https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/svgnoqualityloss.png" width="100%"/>
      <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
    </svg>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcuq7sLb/6/

You could also play with width and height of the image like `height: 100%`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcuq7sLb/7/

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a ton!